# Can I use a SSL certificate for both HTTPS and code signing?

Tags: ssl, https, authenticode

I know very little about code signing and haven't been able to find out any definite answer on the internet about this : is it possible to use a single SSL certificate for running an HTTPS server *and* code-sign Windows executables at the same time?

If yes, what are the advantadges/drawbacks?

Comment: Not unless you can find a CA that will issue a single certificate for both purposes. Each certificate is marked with the uses to which it may be put.

Comment: Any idea about who does this on the internet? None of the major providers appear to be advertising such uses, unless off course you purchase an (expensive) intermediate CA certificate that can be used to create other certificates.